# i have start-time and End-time for a patient visit (in visit table). I want to assign a visit to user(hospital team member)

Tags: sql-server, sql-function

I have start-time and End-time for a patient visit (in visit table). I want to assign a Patient-visit to user(hospital team member).
Can any one help me out for SQl query to find whither **particular** user is **already** assigned or not within that visit date(Start-time and End-Time)?

[image]

**I just want a SQL function where i return 'Already Assigned'  -or-  'free'**

I have a table structure like this

**appointment table**=>
AppointmentId       int 
UserId              nvarchar(128)
ClientVisitId       int 
AppointmentDateTime datetime
StartTime           datetime
EndTime             datetime
Status              int

**ClientVisits tabl**e=>
ClientVisitId       int 
VisitDate           datetime
ClientId             int
StartTime           datetime
EndTime             datetime
ParentClientVisitId int 
UserNote            nvarchar(MAX)
CreatedOn           datetime
NoOfUserRequired    int

Comment: how are visit and appointments tables are related

Comment: appointment table is related with table.Visits(VisitID ). sorry i have not added this column in Appointment table screenshot.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: can explain the values of status from Appointment table

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that if an entry is made into Appointment table it means a user is assigned 
so in order to get patients unassigned to user use the below query

```
SELECT v.VisitId, v.PatientId From Visits v
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Appointment a WHERE a.VisitId=v.VisitId)
```

Comment: the requirement is to find, whither that a particular user is assigned to those visit dates time interval or not.

Comment: @Ali how will we know whether a user is assigned or not

Comment: thanks for your time. In Appointment table, there's  column for userID and visit id which i think helps us.

Comment: @Ali that means if an entry is made into Appointment that visit is assigned for a user

Comment: @Ali so if there is no entry in Appointment that means not assigned right?

Comment: yes, if  there is no entry in appointment for that USER, that means that user is not assigned. BUT it might be possible that user is Appoint in some other visit in some other time or time interval. And we need to find that the user is free for  upcoming visit ?

Comment: @Ali Can please share your table structure for User, Appointment,Visit